# Snowflake task with CRON not scheduled

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I have created a Snowflake task like the one below,

```
CREATE or replace TASK staging.task_name
  WAREHOUSE = 'staging_warehouse'
  SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 1 * * * UTC'
AS
    delete from staging....
```

but I dont the see task scheduled or executed looking at the task history

```
select *
  from table(information_schema.task_history(
    scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd('hour',-10,current_timestamp()),
    result_limit => 10,
    task_name=>'task_name'));
```

I usually run task with minute based schedule and this is the first time using a cron schedule, what might I be missing here?

Comment: I had the same issue, I created a TASK with this cron 
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 49 16 9 9 * Europe/Rome'
And I had resumed the task, but it don't start

Some Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you enable the task and then run the query again?

```
alter task staging.task_name resume;
```